# PHP can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a few PHP servers connecting to my MySQL server through my DNS redirect and the code is a normal mysqli-connection:

```
$db_link = mysqli_connect(server, user, passwort, database, port);
```

2 PHP servers can access the MySQL with this script, 2 can't and I have no idea where to search for the mistake in my system as they are running different Linux OS and PHP versions (5.3-5.8).

Error message:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'servername' (111)

As two of them can connect through the DNS host, I think the MySQL and DNS server shouldn't be a problem.

Has anyone an idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Basic reasons:

- There is no MySQL server running at the specified host
- Connection to the MySQL server is not allowed using TCP-IP. Check the 'skip-networking' setting in the MySQL configuration file (my.ini on Windows, my.cnf on Unix/Linux). It shall be commented out like '#skip-networking'. If it is not commented out, then do it and restart the MySQL server for the change to take effect. SQLyog needs to connect using TCP-IP.
- Some networking issue prevents connection. It could be a network malconfiguration or a firewall issue. We have experienced sometimes that some firewalls (ZoneAlarm in particular) is blocking TCP-IP connections even if it claims to be disabled. Most often it will help to uninstall and reinstall the firewall.
- When trying to connect to a MySQL server at an ISP this error message often indicates that direct connection to MySQL has been blocked. You must then use HTTP-tunneling or SSH-tunneling to connect.
- Also this FAQ may have relevant information. It describes some more special situations when connection to MySQL on Linux

http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Comment: As I´m able to connect from different extern PHP servers, it seems that the config of the MySQL server is right and the port opend correctly, so it's not point 1, 2 or 3. I expect that I have an issue with the config of the php servers.

Comment: if you can connect to another mysql server it mean that with php settings all good. Problem in your mysql server. It can be iptables, error with user permissions, allow ports..  update, if you can, your question and append version of database server with mysql.conf